# Content Management and Community

Tags: community

We need a SF Community that allows

1) document versioning
2) document as an attachment searching
3) folders

Does anyone know of a way to make this happen?

Is there a way to use Content Management with Community? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible within Salesforce community. All you have to do is purchase proper Salesforce Community License.

I believe Salesforce's Customer Community Plus, Partner Community and Employee Apps and Community license would suffice your need.

[image]

Comment: Does it matter which template I use in communities?